# How can I make changes to an automatically generated WCF contract that persist after updating the service contract?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a proxy to wrap a WCF service with ASP.net Core and this is my first time using ASP.Net core.

I am using an auto-generated WCF service contract, and the issue is my WCF service changes frequently, so I must update/refresh the WCF service, and whenever I update my contract, I lose my minor tweaks.

I'm only trying to:

- Hide some properties - *via* changing `public string Property` to `internal string Property`. I've tried `[IgnoreDataMember]` and `[JsonIgnore]` but those don't seem to work
- Make some properties required - *via* `RequiredAttribute`
- Default some property values - *via* `DefaultValueAttribute`

I've tried two approaches so far but they're not working fully.

This represents the automatically generated WCF Contract where I want to require & default `MyProperty1` and hide `MyProperty2`:

```
// This is the automatically generated WCF Contract
public partial class MyClass
{
    private string myPropertyField1;
    private string myPropertyField2;

    public string MyProperty1
    {
        get { return this.myPropertyField1; }
        set { this.myPropertyField1 = value; }
    }
    public string MyProperty2
    {
        get { return this.myPropertyField2; }
        set { this.myPropertyField2 = value; }
    }
}
```

### Method 1:

`ModelMetadataType` to override the contract metdata. This partially works, but not for all attributes for some reason? It feels like a bug.

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(MyClassMetadata))]
public partial class MyClass { }

public partial class MyClassMetadata
{
    [Required]                      // This does not work
    [DefaultValue("SomeValue")]     // This DOES work?
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } // I want this required & defaulted

    [IgnoreDataMember]              // This does not work to hide
    [JsonIgnore]                    // This does not work to hide
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; } // I want this hidden from Swagger view
}
```

Which works to default values, but it doesn't appear to make it required or hidden?

### Method 2:

I tried creating derived class, and then using the derived class instead of `MyClass` for the controller api arguments, but then when I try to call it I receive an error that says something like *Type MyClassDerived was not expected. Use XmlInclude to specify unexpected types...*

```
public partial class MyClassDerived : MyClass
{
    [Required]                          // This puts "*" next to it in Swagger
    [DefaultValue("SomeValue")]         // This defaults the value in Swagger
    public new string MyProperty1
    {
        get { return base.MyProperty1; }
        set { base.MyProperty1 = value; }
    }
    internal new string MyProperty2     // This works to hide from Swagger
    {
        get { return base.MyProperty2; }
        set { base.MyProperty2 = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I hide/default/require contract properties without directly modifying an auto-generated WCF contract service class?

Comment: Do you have option of modifying WCF service?

Comment: If you don't want to update the service reference frequently, you can use the channel factory to call the WCF service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory

Comment: @ZubaerNaseem I do not

Comment: @DingPeng I thought of using that, but I have hundreds of services, each with massive contracts, and it looks like I have to use `Svcutil.exe` to generate the contracts, which would run into the same problem?

Comment: If Im understanding you.. To wrap a contract i would recommend to use a MessageContract with a request/response pattern using your SC, you also can play with the DatacontractSerializer and XMLSerializer to get more flexibility serialzing Datamembers. To solve the DataAnnotations you can create your Custom Attribute with your own logic to hide/default/require depending if SC changes.

Comment: where will you instantiate this? If you are wraping this you could wrap all the plumbing to make the call and recieve the result?

Comment: I do not know is it possible to change variable accessibility levels without rewriting the file itself, the thing i do know, that you could parse values to a new class, which includes new variables with property of accessibility level you try to give, in your example it is "internal"

Comment: Can you show the controller method?

Comment: why not apply your changes on WSDL file and use the edited file?